# IndexError: list index out of range [python irc bot]

Tags: python, python-2.7, bots

For my IRC bot when I try to use the `db addcol command I will get that Index error but I got no idea what is wrong with it.

```
@hook.command(adminonly=True, autohelp=False)
def db(inp,db=None):
    split = inp.split(' ')
    action = split[0]
    if "init" in action:
        result = db.execute("create table if not exists users(nick primary key, host, location, greeting, lastfm, fines, battlestation, desktop, horoscope, version)")
        db.commit()
        return result
    elif "addcol" in action:
        table = split[1]
        col = split[2]
        if table is not None and col is not None:
        db.execute("ALTER TABLE {} ADD COLUMN {}".format(table,col))
            db.commit
            return "Added Column"
```

That is the command I am trying to execute and here is the error:

```
Unhandled exeption in thread started by <function run at 0xb70d6844
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core/main.py", line 68, in run
    out = func(input.inp, **kw)
  File "plugins/core_admin_global.py", :ine 308, in db
    col = split[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You will find the whole code at my [GIT repository](https://github.com/FrozenPigs/Taigabot).

Edit: This bot is just a little thing I have been playing around with while learning python so don't expect me to be too knowledgeable about this.

Yet another edit:
The command I am trying  to add, just replace desktop with mom.

```
@hook.command(autohelp=False)
def desktop(inp, nick=None, conn=None, chan=None,db=None, notice=None):
    "desktop http://url.to/desktop | @ nick -- Shows a users Desktop."
    if inp:
        if "http" in inp:
            database.set(db,'users','desktop',inp.strip(),'nick',nick)
            notice("Saved your desktop.")
            return
        elif 'del' in inp:
            database.set(db,'users','desktop','','nick',nick)
            notice("Deleted your desktop.")
            return
        else:
            if '@' in inp: nick = inp.split('@')[1].strip()
            else: nick = inp.strip()

    result = database.get(db,'users','desktop','nick',nick)
    if result:
        return '{}: {}'.format(nick,result)
    else:
        if not '@' in inp: notice(desktop.__doc__)
        return 'No desktop saved for {}.'.format(nick)
```

Comment: I know little to nothing about this bot. And that is still one of the things I have yet to figure out.

Comment: Well why not add `print(input.inp)` to the top of the function, and see what it says?

Comment: Apologies - in that scope, it would be `print(inp)`

Comment: I see that one point in the code for main it says input.inp = input.paraml

Comment: What exactly is the command you're giving the function? Do you type it in manually? This is why I suggest you `print(inp)` in `db` (or `print(input.paraml` in `run`); so you can see the command being given.

Comment: This is the command I am trying to add.
Adding it to the main post.

Comment: The code you have added does not appear to be relevant. Where in that do you call `db` to add a column?

Comment: To add a column in the irc you do `db addcol mom but then I get the index error.

Comment: Well no wonder - it is expecting `"db addcol tablename colname"` and you're only giving one of those pieces of information

Comment: Get an error for that no such table.

Comment: Then presumably the `tablename` you supply doesn't correspond to a table in the database.